# Woocommerce subscriptions hook scheduled_subscription_payment_ passes parent order instead of a renewall one

Tags: woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm trying Paymaster Recurring payments into exsisting payment gateway.

the standart hook calling looks like this

```
add_action('scheduled_subscription_payment_'. $this->id , array($this, 'scheduled_subscription_payment'), 10, 2);
```

It's fine and clear.
Here's the function processing calling:

```
function scheduled_subscription_payment( $amount_to_charge, $order ) {
    $this->process_subscription_payment($order, $amount_to_charge);
}
```

nothing special but there's a problem: according official documentation `$order` parameter should be automatically created by Woocommerce Subscriptions engine order - but I recieve a parent order which has already been processed.

I initiate payment process by `Run` button in `Sheduled actions`: renewal order is created but never passed to the function shown before. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343242/woocommerce-get-new-order-id-on-subscription-renewal). One guy faced the same problem so the problem was that hook `scheduled_subscription_payment_` had been deprecated and we should use `woocommerce_scheduled_subscription_payment_` instead